# How to get mentioned roles ids in slash command pycord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, pycord

```
@bot.slash_command(name = "test", description = "testing command")
async def test(ctx, mention: discord.Option(name="mention", description="mention.", required=True)):
        print(mention.mentions.role_mentions)
```

i tried to do this but throws error that says str has no attribute mentions

i am trying to get all mentioned roles ids in pycord and got error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not specified the type for the `mention` parameter - by default this is a string (hence your error that "str has no attribute mentions"). The first arg to `discord.Option` should be the type of the option - the library will then convert that and allow you to select mentionables when using the slash command and you'll have a mentionable object type in the code when the slash command is used. [Perhaps consider re-reading this section in the guides.](https://guide.pycord.dev/interactions/application-commands/slash-commands#options--option-types)

```py
@bot.slash_command(name = "test", description = "testing command")
async def test(
    ctx,
    mention: discord.Option(
        discord.SlashCommandOptionType.mentionable,
        name="mention",
        description="mention.",
        required=True
    )
):
    # whatever you want to do with that here
```